# How to get MAC address of Access point in java?

Tags: java, mac-address

How can I capture the MAC address (hardware address) of any access point in Java?

Comment: go through this[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333344/how-do-i-get-the-hosts-mac-address-using-java-5]

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple access point and you know `ip-addresses` of these point than you can do

```
InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByName("enter ip here");
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(add);
```

Take a look at [NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress%28%29) method of [NetworkInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) class in java. It returns

> Returns the hardware address (usually MAC) of the interface if it has
>   one and if it can be accessed given the current privileges.